# Add custom css file after plugin css with Wordpress Child Theme functions.php

Tags: functions, child-theme, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I am trying to enque a css file thorugh my child themes `functions.php` after a specific plugin css file with the handle `openpos.bill.bootstrap`. Unfortunately the current code does not load anything. **Any idea how to solve this problem?**

Plugin uses the following code block to load styles

```
public function initScripts(){
    global $op_in_pos_screen;
    global $op_in_bill_screen;
    global $op_in_kitchen_screen;
    if($op_in_pos_screen)
    {
        add_action( 'init', array($this,'registerScripts') ,10 );
    }
    if($op_in_bill_screen)
    {
        add_action( 'init', array($this,'registerBillScripts') ,10 );
    }
    if($op_in_kitchen_screen)
    {
        add_action( 'init', array($this,'registerKitchenScripts') ,10 );
    }
    add_filter('script_loader_tag',  array($this,'add_async_attribute'), 10, 2);
}

public function registerBillScripts(){
    $info = $this->_core->getPluginInfo();

    wp_enqueue_style('openpos.bill.bootstrap', OPENPOS_URL.'/assets/css/bootstrap.css') // load my custom css after this one

    // ... and so on

}
```

My code to load my custom style.css file which fails to load anything

```
function load_custom_css_to_style_billing_screen() {
    wp_enqueue_style('bill-screen-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/include-parts-from-functions-php-file/frontend-related/plugins/openpos-plugin/pos-app/css/bill-screen-style.css',array('openpos.bill.bootstrap'));
    }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_css_to_style_billing_screen', 10 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The original stylesheet is enqueued as `openpos.bill.bootstrap`

```
wp_enqueue_style('openpos.bill.bootstrap', OPENPOS_URL.'/assets/css/bootstrap.css') // load my custom css after this one
```

But you've set `openpos.bill.style` as the dependency:

```
wp_enqueue_style('bill-screen-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/include-parts-from-functions-php-file/frontend-related/plugins/openpos-plugin/pos-app/css/bill-screen-style.css',array('openpos.bill.style'));
```

These need to be the same.

Comment: changed it to the right handle but it does not work...